# How to clear a ManyToMany Field in a patch request?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

My ManyToMany Relationship doesn't reset. I'm doing a patch requests that translates into djrf's partial_update. But afterwards `RecordUsersEntry` still has the same users saved it got from `setup_entry`.

I've tried a put request with field and record, and then the many to many relationship is resetted, but I want to reset it with a patch request.

Might be related to: https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/issues/2883, however I'm going to use JSON Requests and at the moment I'm only concerned about how to get this test green.

I've written the follwing test:

```
def test_entry_update(self):
    self.setup_entry()
    view = RecordUsersEntryViewSet.as_view(actions={'patch': 'partial_update'})
    data = {
        'users': []
    }
    request = self.factory.patch('', data=data)
    force_authenticate(request, self.user)
    response = view(request, pk=1)
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
    entry = RecordUsersEntry.objects.first()
    self.assertEqual(entry.users.all().count(), UserProfile.objects.none().count())  # <-- The test fails here
```

with

```
def setup_entry(self):
    self.entry = RecordUsersEntry.objects.create(record=self.record, field=self.field)
    self.entry.users.set(UserProfile.objects.all())
```

and the model looks like this:

```
class RecordUsersEntry(RecordEntry):
    record = models.ForeignKey(Record, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='users_entries')
    field = models.ForeignKey(RecordUsersField, related_name='entries', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    users = models.ManyToManyField(UserProfile, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ['record', 'field']
        verbose_name = 'RecordUsersEntry'
        verbose_name_plural = 'RecordUsersEntries'

    def __str__(self):
        return 'recordUsersEntry: {};'.format(self.pk)
```

Viewsets and Serializer just being the basic ones:

```
class RecordUsersEntryViewSet(mixins.CreateModelMixin, mixins.UpdateModelMixin, mixins.DestroyModelMixin,
                              GenericViewSet):
    queryset = RecordUsersEntry.objects.none()
    serializer_class = RecordUsersEntrySerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        # every field returned because they are supposed to be seen by everybody
        return RecordUsersEntry.objects.filter(record__template__rlc=self.request.user.rlc)
```

Serializer:

```
class RecordUsersEntrySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = RecordUsersEntry
        fields = '__all__'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out, I had to specify the format, because it seems like the tests are otherwise sending it in `multipart/form-data` which doesn't work, see: https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/issues/2883

Therefore, this works:

```
request = self.factory.patch('', data=data, format='json')
```